# Use ngSwitch to switch between components in Angular 11 a href?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-switch

I have to child components and I want to be able to switch between two sub components but it not working. I have no idea how to implement it here.

This is my example code

HTML

```
<h3 class="first">Choose View</h3>
<a options="A">A</a>
<a options="B">B</a>
<p>Selected Type: <span style="font-weight: bold">{{selectedType}}</span></p>

<!-- Switching Mechanism -->

<div [ngSwitch]="selectedType">
  <li *ngSwitchCase="'A'"> <app-component-a></app-component-a>
  <li *ngSwitchCase="'B'">  <app-component-b></app-component-b>
  <li *ngSwitchDefault><app-component-b></app-component-b>
</div>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-mf7vca)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are:

- Missing closing tags
- `li` inside of a div
- Not sure what `options="A"` is supposed to do, you need to set the selectedType variable

```
<h3 class="first">Choose View</h3>
<a (click)="selectedType='A'">A</a><br />
<a (click)="selectedType='B'">B</a>
<p>Selected Type: <span style="font-weight: bold">{{selectedType}}</span></p>

<!-- Switching Mechanism -->

<ul [ngSwitch]="selectedType">
  <li *ngSwitchCase="'A'"> <app-component-a></app-component-a></li>
  <li *ngSwitchCase="'B'">  <app-component-b></app-component-b></li>
  <li *ngSwitchDefault><app-component-b></app-component-b></li>
</ul>
```

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-mrhp85)

Instead of using ngSwitch you could more simply do this:

```
<app-component-a *ngIf="selectedType == 'A'"></app-component-a>
<app-component-b *ngIf="selectedType != 'A'"></app-component-b>
```